# How can two people work on the same Xcode project with same bundle ID

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

Right so I am working on an Xcode project with a friend that uses in-App Purchases, and he has registered the project to App Store Connect. However, when I run the app to test, I have to change the Bundle ID, as it's registered to his account, thus returning an error when I try to test the In-App Purchases. Is there any way that the both of us can work on the same Bundle ID that is linked to the project in Connect?

Comment: You'll need to be on the same dev team (ie organization).

Comment: He’ll need to invite you to his development team. You’ll then need to create a development certificate on his team, and then edit the provisioning profile for the app to include your newly created development certificate. You’ll also need to register any physical devices you’re using to sideload to to their development team.

Comment: We are both registered as Individual developers; I don't think it's possible... Any other ways?

Comment: He can share his username and password with you...

Comment: That's hardly an option...